# JavaScript not retrieving text from textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS and am frustrated.  Nothing I do seems to get this script to pull the text from the textboxes.  The first alert box displays the message "Hello".  After that, no other alert boxes display.  Also, the innerHTML code doesn't post any HTML to the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>


    <form>

      Number 1:
      <input type="text" value=" "  id="number1"></input> 
    <br />
    Number 2:
    <input type="text" value=" "  id="number2"></input>
  <br />
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate"></input>
<p id="product"></p>
</form>



<script>
  function calculate() {
    alert("Hello");
    var num1, num2;
    num1 = Number(document.getElementbyId("number1").value);
    alert(num1);
    num2 = Number(document.getElementbyId("number2").value);

    var prod = num1 * num2;
    alert(prod);
    document.getElementbyId("product").innerHTML=prod;
  }
</script>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `.getElementbyid` with [`.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) (note the "B" in uppercase). Your script is breaking when reaches there with this error: *Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function*

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

If I could offer a tip: always check **console** when developing JavaScript, it should be the first place to look when something goes wrong.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/0119L7dc/

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, it's there

Comment: Need stronger glasses.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong call to DOM function `getElementById`. In javascript everything is case sensitive. Just be aware of that, you are using `getElementbyId` with the B of ById in lowerCase.

Follow a working version:

```js
function calculate() {
  alert("Hello");
  var num1, num2;
  num1 = Number(document.getElementById("number1").value);
  alert(num1);
  num2 = Number(document.getElementById("number2").value);

  var prod = num1 * num2;
  alert(prod);
  debugger;
  document.getElementById("product").innerHTML=prod;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      Number 1:
      <input type="text" value=" "  id="number1"></input> 
    <br />
    Number 2:
    <input type="text" value=" "  id="number2"></input>
  <br />
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate"></input>
<p id="product"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```